# Reserve bytes in stack: x86 Assembly (64 bit)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $32, %rsp
```

I have big question regarding explanation of "$32" in third instruction. The information from search and blogs specifies that in above third instruction we are reserving certain "bytes" of space for stack. From doc, %rsp is 64 bit register and %esp is 32 bit.

Is "$32" means 32 bytes ?($number means constant ?) If yes then how are we allocating 32 bytes on 64 bit register? Above instruction were generated from "otool". I am using macbook pro.

I am just trying to learn a small things about assembly.

Thanks.

Comment: Learning small things will be easier with a book than with disassembling foreign binaries.

Comment: @a3f those instructions are in books too. So could you please answer if you know ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is "$32" means 32 bytes ?($number means constant ?) If yes then how are we allocating 32 bytes on 64 bit register?

These 32 bytes are not allocated *on 64 bit register*. They are allocated on the stack. By lowering the stackpointer (which is in %rsp) the address range from %rsp to %rsp+31 is at our disposal for storing data.

Comment: Ok i get it. What is the size of stack then ? Who determines that ? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer, the OS or even your compiler. Whoever sets the stackpointer. The distinction between x86-32 and x86-64 is basically __how__ you treat the stack, not its __size__.

Comment: So lastly, i need not be allocating that size, i just need to worry about stackpointer address range ? Thanks again.

Comment: The __32 bytes__ from your example constitute _a size_ as well as _an address range_. My previous comment was about the total size of the stack which in normal use could be very large indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In 64-bit code, 128 bytes are reserved for you already, so you don't have to mess with the stack pointer in leaf functions, which consequently means you probably don't have to push/pop %rbp.  Just use %rsp-128 to %rsp-1 for your data.

This reserved area is called the [red-zone](/questions/tagged/red-zone):

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/

Comment: Important note about red-zone: it is not 64 bit code specific. It is *Linux x86-64* specific. No such things on Windows, for example.

Comment: To be clear though, that's MS not following the AMD/Intel spec. The spec for ABI says there's a red zone and it should be present on Linux and Unix, including OS X.